# Firebase storage in Android when upload file as putStream, In onProgressListener TaskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount() returns -1

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase storage to upload a file from Android app. After getting file storage reference from `FirebaseStorage`, uploading file properly with `uploadTask`. What my finding is, during `onProgress` listener of `uploadTask`, `taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount()` is -1. 
whereas, `taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()` is giving proper result. Is it a bug from Firebase?

N.b: file is uploading with no issue.

here is my code snapshot:

```
    try {
        uploadTask = fileReference.putStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(this, new
            OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

           // here taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount() is -1 

            double progressPersentage = ((taskSnapshot
                    .getBytesTransferred() * 100.0) / taskSnapshot
                    .getTotalByteCount());// for file transfer
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), taskSnapshot
                    .getTotalByteCount() + " Uploading " + (taskSnapshot
                    .getBytesTransferred()));
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Because a stream represents a sequence of bytes of unspecified length, it's not unreasonable that `getTotalByteCount()` would be unknown.

You'll get better results using [putFile()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#putFile(android.net.Uri)):

```
uploadTask = fileReference.putFile(Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the nice info. yes putFile() worked well on that case. thanks again.